# Make a certain program use internet as the only one by iptables

Tags: linux, connection, iptables

I implemented a method introduced in https://askubuntu.com/a/997525/672396
My program should work after that but did not. The message that terminal returned was

`ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

You can see all I did:

```
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -j DROP
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match has-internet
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
u@h ~
$ ls -l myping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u has-internet 8 May 29 14:36 myping
u@h ~
$ cat myping 
ping $1
u@h ~
$ ./myping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -D OUTPUT 2
u@h ~
$ ./myping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.179.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=31.3 ms
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=24.3 ms
64 bytes from ams17s10-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.179.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=29.4 ms
```

`myping` program is this:

```
ping $1
```

How to repair it?
Thank you

## EDIT

I corrected and still doesn't work:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet -j ACCEPT
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
u@h ~
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner GID match has-internet
u@h ~
$ ./myping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
u@h ~
```

## EDIT2

I add a privilege

```
sudo chmod g+s myping
```

And make `has-internet` the first group of the owner. It still doesn't work.

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner 1001 -j ACCEPT
u@h ~
$ ls -l myping 
-rwxr-sr-x 1 has-internet has-internet 13 May 30 09:43 myping
u@h ~
$ ./myping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
u@h ~
```

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot :

the first line should be :

`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet -j ACCEPT`

instead of

`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner has-internet`

bonus : you can change the default policy to DROP instead of adding a DROP statement with :

`iptables -P OUTPUT DROP`

instead of

`sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 2 -j DROP`

also, add the setgid bit on myping so it is executed as the group owner instead of the user

`sudo chmod g+s myping`

Comment: I corrected and still doesn't work.

Comment: edited my answer to add the setgid bit on myping

Comment: perhaps setgid is not relevant, but I found someone that describe this as a bug : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373703/unable-to-get-iptables-owner-module-gid-owner-to-work

it basically seems to check the primary group of the owner instead of the group of the file like we would expect

Comment: Added a second edit to the question. It still doesn't work.

Comment: there is a small misunderstanding... it should be the primary group of the user that executes the program ("u" in your example) So "u" should have "has-internet" as his primary group